# In ImageMagick 6.9.10-12, getting "too many exceptions(exception processing is suspended)" just for identify operation

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-identify

When I run a simple command identify /dir/*.tiffs, due to many warnings of 
Unknown field with tag 32934
incorrect count for field "Tag 32934" etc.

The identify operation stopped with error status.

This looks like something that was introduced in 6.9.6 to prevent some security issue with imagemagick.

Comment: Try `identity -define tiff:ignore-tags=32934 someImage.tif` and see if that helps. If there are other troublesome tags, add the additional ones using commas as separators.

Comment: If those are warnings, then use -quiet to suppress them. `identify -quiet /dir/*.tiffs`. If they are errors, then this will not help.

Comment: It doesn't seem to work, still output says unknown field with tag 32934

Comment: It is weird because it still goes ahead to identify the images, just ends with status non-zero

Comment: Can you post a link to one of your tiff files so we can examine and test it? How were those tiff file created?  What is your exact Imagemagick version (6.9.6.x) and date and platform? `convert -version` will tell you the version and date. Also what version of TIFF are you using. `convert -list format` will tell you that. See the end of the line for TIFF for the version number.